# Connection to MySQL Server takes 30+ seconds

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, redhat

I'm running into an issue with a handful of my MySQL servers. Within our enterprise environment, my team was provisioned 3 servers, 2 running `RHEL 6.9` with DB `Server version: 5.6.36-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)`, the third running `Ubuntu 16.04` and mysql client `(Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19)`.

For clarity I'm going to refer to the servers by IP.

```
DB1: 10.0.0.1
DB2: 10.0.0.2
APP: 10.0.0.3
```

When I'm shelled in directly to `10.0.0.3`, and try to connect to either DB, I get a long 30s pause before the connection opens and I receive my mysql > prompt.

I use `mysql -h 10.0.0.1 -u myuser --password=mypassword` to try and connect.

I made sure that the 3306 port was open. I have tested the latency between servers, which is less than .1ms. My network team moved the two VMs onto the same host to try and further minimize network latency.

The connection doesn't seem to drop, it just hangs for a long while before the connection opens up. When I hook up my application to either DB, the application experiences the same behavior and becomes too slow to use.

Comment: It's possible your server is set up to resolve reverse DNS, something that's typically problematic for private IPs. You'll need to check the config. As a note, this is probably a [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) question.

Comment: Spot on @tadman

Comment: Been there before, feel your pain!